# Jar files for java.util.regex

Tags: java

I need jar files for java.util.regex in my project for input validation if any one can help please help me.Please provide me some websites from where i can download it. Thank you.

Comment: Erm....  It's packaged in the base Java runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `java.util.regex` is bundled with the standard Java runtime. (Which means that you don't need to include a separate .jar file to access it.)

To answer your question: It's in the `rt.jar` file.

Comment: Yes I found it but it does not allow me to download... so how can i download it? Thank you..

Comment: If you have Java installed on your computer, you already have it. Search for `rt.jar` on your harddrive! :-)

Comment: Ok my problem of adding jar file is solved but it does not allow me to use charSequence data type it says me to change it by string.. I had also find for converting string in char sequence but not any thing worked here properly...

Answer (score 2):

The [`java.util.regex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) package was added to Java SE 1.4.  If you are running an older version of java than that you should really consider upgrading.

Comment: Ok thank you...But can u say me how to upgrade it to Java SE 1.4.. Even if how can i know that which Java SE i am using Thank You..

Comment: Ok my problem of adding jar file is solved but it does not allow me to use charSequence data type it says me to change it by string..

Answer (score 1):

The `regex` classes are in the standard `rt.jar` that comes with every JDK or JRE download. You almost certainly already have them.